# IMFTopoLoader::Load fails with generic E_FAIL

Tags: c++, windows, video, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

This is a long shot, but maybe someone out there has had this problem before?

I'm building a topology that has multiple sinks and a few transforms between the source and renderers (video only for now). The source is a capture device (webcam).

For uncompressed video sources everything works fine. However when I change the source format to MJPEG and add a corresponding decoder into the topology I get a generic `E_FAIL` response from the `MFTopoLoader::Load()` method that I can't seem to be able to resolve.

All the renderer sinks are properly bound to output windows (no sink writers in this topo), source activated/configured, none of the intermediate `IMFMediaType`'s are set (I expect the `Load()` to perform this operation).

The way I add the decoder is as follows (happy path):

1. create an `MF_TOPOLOGY_TRANSFORM_NODE`
2. list the available decoders for the video format and chose one (user-selected, but there's only one available on the system for MJPEG anyway)
3. `CoCreateInstance()` with the decoder `CLSID` and a `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER` context
4. `GetAttributes()` store for the decoder MFT

   1. `CopyAllItems()` from decoder MFT into the node
5. `SetObject()` to decoder MFT on the node
6. Add the node into topology
7. Connect the decoder

The above steps succeed and it is only the `MFTopoLoader::Load()` that fails.

Once again - the pipeline works just fine as long as there's no decoder in it (so only works for uncompressed videos) yet the same code fails once I add a decoder.

I'm running on Windows 10

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the decoder. Why not try some others.

Comment: That is a system stock decoder which works just fine when auto-added into topology with the `IMFSession::SetTopology()` and no "no resolve" flag set on it. It only fails when I add it manually and loading the topology (before calling the `SetTopology()`)